# How can I stop a QApplication from showing up in the dock?

Tags: c++, qt, command-line, window, qapplication

I'm making a console application on OS X that interacts with specific parts of the Desktop Environment (mainly the mouse using QCursor), so I cannot use a QCoreApplication (despite how much I want to).

The application works fine, it is just that it shows up in the dock whenever I run it from the command line. I looked at several other questions online, but none fixed the problem I'm having.

I looked into `QSystemTrayIcon`, and I would be fine with using it IF it would get rid of the pesky window that pops up. Here is my code narrowed down to a minimum that still has the problem I addressed above.

The .pro:

```
TARGET = project

QT += core
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QCursor cur;
    cur.setPos(0,0);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue with Qt5@Linux. Your code sets cursor to (0,0) without any windows and continues running `a.exec` until I manually stop it.

Comment: @Sergey Huh. It opens a window for me...

Comment: @FlareCat How about [hiding it manually](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/disable-the-dock-icon-for-any-application.php)?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto Thanks! I was going to try to keep it as a standalone executable, but I'll give that a shot soon.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto Thanks! It worked. If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be doing it manually as describe here.

> Luckily, if it is a cocoa application, you can hide the Dock icon yourself. To see if it is possible, right-click (Control-click) on the application icon. If "Show Package Contents" is in the menu that appears, you can hide the icon in the Dock.
>
> If this is the case, select "Show Package Contents" and look for the `"Info.plist"` file inside the Contents folder. Open this file using TextEdit by right-clicking on it and choosing "Open With - Other" from the menu.
>
> In the file, paste the following two lines just after  on the 6th line:
>
> ```
> <key>LSUIElement</key>
> <string>1</string>
> ```
>
> Save the file and close it. For the changes to take effect, you need to move the application to the desktop and them back to its original location (OS X keeps a cache of the file, so you need to trick it into checking it again).
>
> Now when you open the application, no icon will appear in the Dock.

Source: http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/disable-the-dock-icon-for-any-application.php